# Can you help me solve this problem in Latex? Shipout\background shipiout\ferground?

Tags: latex

this sentences `Shipout\background shipiout\ferground` showed in source files!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to update your latex version.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it has solved my problem